# Ubuntu sed creates duplicate lines instead of returning just one replaced line

Tags: php, bash, magento, ubuntu, sed

I have below script to extract the current open file path in Gedit.

```
#!/bin/bash
origPath=$GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_URI
if [[ $origPath == *"smb"* ]]
then
    finalPath=`php -f /var/www/html/pathswapcmd.php smb_path=$origPath`;
else
    finalPath=$origPath;
fi
## echo -n $finalPath;
echo -n $finalPath | sed 's/^.*app/app/p' | xclip -sel clip;
exit;
```

Generally I have Magento files in my system so my path needs to start from `app`, `skin` folders etc. only.

Now when I try to remove everything before `app` with `sed` it removes but it gives the path three times separated with a junk character which is not identifiable(ofcourse) in the address bar of Ubuntu folder manager.

I want simple and clear solution of removing duplicate lines from `sed` command.

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: @Epodax `finalPath=\`php -f /var/www/html/pathswapcmd.php smb_path=$origPath\`;` ?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude, but is it relevant to know the php script output ? As if I remove the `sed` line then it gives me path just fine and only once in the clipboard, but when I use `sed` then it gives duplicate paths separated by junk character (probably newline char). I is just that I have used php script to detect if the path is `smb` based or `ftp` based.

Answer (score 1):

`s/pattern/replacement/p` will output the line buffer after any manipulation is done by default, and also output it again if replacement was performed due to `p` flag. Remove the `p` flag to avoid printing the substituted line again, or supply the `-n` argument to `sed` to avoid printing each line.

```
sed -n 's/pattern/replacement/p'  # print only lines where replacement happened

sed 's/pattern/replacement/'      # print all lines, possibly with replacements
```

Comment: If I remove `p` flag then do I need to put some other char in it's place ? or just like `sed 's/^.*app/app/'` Please answer in complete format and code. Also post any reference links you have.

Comment: Thanks it works, but how to remove junk character at the end of the replaced line ?

Comment: What junk character?

Comment: Probably a newline character, but it shows as junk in Ubuntu address bar of folder manager.

Comment: @Amadan Guessing it is a carriage return?

Comment: Yes it is I am mostly sure.

Comment: No still same problem.

Comment: @VickyDev `sed 's/\r//'`

Comment: `sed 's/.../.../' | tr -d '\n' | ...`? Or rather... why are you making us guess? Show us what `echo -n $finalPath | xxd` gives you.